# Django ManyToManyField options

Tags: django, models, manytomanyfield

It is possible to give `blank=True, null=True` to ManyToManyField without having problems?
Or maybe I doing something wrong with my code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `null=True`.

`blank=True` will make that field optional.